# read 'df -h' output as array of lines in bash

Tags: bash, array

I am trying to read "df -h" output as array of lines in shell script.

I tried the below code, but its var[0] is giving me the first column of first line instead of the whole first line.
My expectation is to get the complete line in one iteration.

```
var=($(df -k))
echo " echo ${var[0]}
```

How can I achieve this without using awk?

Comment: Can you clarify which shell you're working in?

Comment: i am using bash

Answer (score 2):

`$(cmd)` (command substitution) left unquoted in list contexts invokes the split+glob operator in POSIX shells like `bash`. Here, you don't want the glob part. The split part splits on characters found in `$IFS` (space, tab and newline by default).

So here, you'd want:

```
IFS='
' # split on newline only. Also IFS=$'\n' in bash/ksh93/zsh/mksh
set -o noglob  # disable globbing
lines=($(df -k)) # use the split+glob operator
```

(note that it removes empty lines).

That also works with `mksh`, `yash`, `ksh93` or `zsh` (with `zsh` you may omit the `set -o noglob`, as zsh does only splitting, not globbing upon command substitution).

Alternatively, you could do (bash specific):

```
readarray -t lines < <(df -k)
```

Note that there's no guarantee that there will be one line per entry in the output of `df`, and that [doing text processing with shell loops is generally not the way to go](/q/169716). Also note that while array indices start at 0 in bash and ksh, they start at 1 in all other shells.